# Mapping list of objects

Tags: c#, dao, dto, object-object-mapping

I'm manually creating a mapper that converts a DAO object to a DTO. *** BTW, I'm aware of AutoMappers but I want to do this by hand for a few reasons.

The mapper itself is not difficult. What I need help with is mapping a List. Do I need to handle each object mapping in a foreach loop or is there a better way to create a mapper that can handle both mapping a single object as well as a list of objects?

My DAO object looks like this:

```
MyObjectDao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say my DTO object looks like this:

```
MyObjectDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And my mapper is as simple as this:

```
public MyObjectDto ConvertFromDaoToDto(MyObjectDao daoObject)
{
   MyObjectDto dtoObject = new MyObjectDto();
   dtoObject.Id = daoObject.Id;
   dtoObject.Name = dtoObject.Name;

   return dtoObject;
}
```

As I mentioned above, I can go through a FOREACH loop to handle mapping of each DAO object to a DTO object but is there a better way to handle a list of objects?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Are you just wanting a simple way to turn a list of `MyObjectDao` into a list of `MyObjectDto`? If so: `MyDAOList.Select(ConvertFromDaoToDto)` will get you an `IEnumerable`. Add `.ToList()` if you really need a list.

Comment: That's what I was asking. Thank you! The MyDaoList.Select to handle converting a list of Dao objects to Dto.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started).

I would also  create a MyObjectDtoMapper class to encapsulate conversion:

```
public class MyObjectDtoMapper 
{
    public MyObjectDtoMapper()
    {
        // configure AutoMapper here
    }

    public MyObjectDto Map(MyObjectDao daoObject)
    {
       var dtoObject = // map from daoObject with AutoMapper
       return dtoObject;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyObjectDto> Map(IEnumerable<MyObjectDao> daoObjects)
    {
       return daoObjects.Select(Map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that for simple POCO's Automapper is probably a bit overkill. Plus it's one of the slowest mappers out there.

Comment: @JamieR I wouldn't say it's an overkill, I believe this is a very clean approach, especially when the classes grow. Speaking of speed - you might be right, but honestly I haven't noticed any performance issues.

Comment: It's all down to opinion really, but I prefer ValueInjector over automapper, especially for speed and it's cleaner.

Comment: I'm extremely concerned about speed/performance which is one of the primary reasons why I decided to handle it manually. Application's performance is absolutely paramount for us. If we need to do some additional work, we're willing to do it so that we don't compromise performance.

Comment: @Sam Ok, stay away from AutoMapper than :). However you still may consider encapsulating mapping logic in a mapper class.

Comment: @gisek I will look at encapsulating the mapping logic. Thanks!